# SQL Server Query Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

A table with a date column like

```
create table OrderSold
(
  ID int primary key identity,
  SellDate date null,
  CustID
)
```

Now is there any difference in performance in below two, which one will be recommended most

Query #1

```
select ID 
from OrderSold 
where SellDate = '2014-01-31'
```

and

Query #2

```
select ID 
from OrderSold 
where SellDate = '01/31/2014'
```

and

Query #3

```
declare @MyDate date = '2014-01-31'

select ID 
from OrderSold 
where SellDate = @MyDate
```

Thanks..

Comment: #2 is language dependent because of the format of the string representing the date - will work on some system, fail on others. #1 doesn't have that problem, since it's using the ISO-8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD` which works on all SQL Servers, with all language and regional settings

Comment: #1 or #3 is recommended. For #2 you need to convert the format from string to Date. :)

Comment: @marc_s, "even if you try to use the seemingly unambiguous YYYY-MM-DD, this can break under certain scenarios -- such as when the user's language settings are set to French" https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries so, the best option is `YYYYMMDD`. In terms of performance they are the same.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov that only applies to the legacy datatypes not `date` as here.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: it breaks when using `DATETIME` - but it **works** when using `DATE` ! (as the OP does here)

Comment: @marc_s and @MartinSmith, point taken. It indeed applies only to `datetime` and `smalldatetime`, as Aaron writes in the article, but I was completely surprised that `YYYY-MM-DD` can be misinterpreted and believe it is worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's make a little test. First let's populate the table with 1.000.000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE OrderSold
    (
      ID INT PRIMARY KEY
             IDENTITY ,
      SellDate DATE NULL ,
      CustID INT
    )
GO


DECLARE @i INT = 1000000

WHILE @i >= 0
    BEGIN

        INSERT  INTO dbo.OrderSold
                ( SellDate, CustID )
        VALUES  ( DATEADD(dd, -@i % 1000, GETDATE()), -- SellDate - date
                  @i  -- CustID - int
                  )
        SET @i = @i - 1
    END
```

Now let's see actual execution plans on a heap:

[image]

As you see execution plans are the same.

Now let's create a non clustered covering index on the heap:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_OrderSold_SellDate ON dbo.OrderSold(SellDate) INCLUDE(ID)
```

Let's see execution plans:

[image]

As you can see plans are the same again. The only difference is between scan and seek. So the answer to your question is: there is absolutely no difference between those 3 statements.

Also notice, as mentioned by @marc_s and @Imran Ali Khan,

```
select ID 
from OrderSold 
where SellDate = '01/31/2014'
```

this format is language dependent and may not work on some instances. But as those 3 statement are valid and runnable, they would be the same from performance viewpoint.

EDIT:

As mentioned by @Martin Smith, this emulation was not completely correct. Let's add additional 4 rows to table:

```
INSERT  INTO dbo.OrderSold
        ( SellDate, CustID )
VALUES  ( '20150224', -- SellDate - date
          1  -- CustID - int
          )

INSERT  INTO dbo.OrderSold
        ( SellDate, CustID )
VALUES  ( '20150224', -- SellDate - date
          2  -- CustID - int
          )

INSERT  INTO dbo.OrderSold
        ( SellDate, CustID )
VALUES  ( '20150224', -- SellDate - date
          3  -- CustID - int
          )

INSERT  INTO dbo.OrderSold
        ( SellDate, CustID )
VALUES  ( '20150224', -- SellDate - date
          4  -- CustID - int
          )     

SELECT  ID
FROM    OrderSold
WHERE   SellDate = '2015-02-24'

SELECT  ID
FROM    OrderSold
WHERE   SellDate = '02/24/2015'


DECLARE @MyDate DATE = '2015-02-24'
SELECT  ID
FROM    OrderSold
WHERE   SellDate = @MyDate
```

[image]

As you can see now there is difference, because estimated rows count was 999 and actual rows count is 4(when estimated rows count of first 2 statements are 4). This is because of parameter sniffing problem. Optimizer doesn't know what is the value of variable is and average density of column from statistics comes into play. Here it is 1000.

But you can use query hint OPTION(RECOMPILE) to work around this problem. You can read about it here for example:

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/using-recompile-query-hint-solve-parameter-sniffing-problems

Comment: 1+ for the detailed explanation with execution plan

Comment: If you make a non clustered non covering index you will be able to see a difference between 1 and 3 with the right cardinalities. As variables aren't sniffed. It will be possible for the one with literals to use a plan with lookups and other not or vice versa.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I've tested and yes there is minor difference. I will update answer.

Comment: You would need to be testing a situation where the proportion of rows with the literal value under test and the proportion of rows guessed in the plan with variable were on different sides of the tipping point between plan with lookups and plan without.

Comment: very nice ... +1 for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID 
from OrderSold 
where SellDate = '2014-01-31'
```

is better due to it is ISO8601 format, 
for more details about date time read this

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

on above link its describe in details